# SBT dependency for flink-azure-fs-hadoop fails

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to store my checkpoints in azure BLOB storage. According to flink 1.9-SNAPSHOT docs this should be possible. However when I try add the SBT dependency I get the following error:

The SBT dependency:
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-azure-fs-hadoop" %"1.9-SNAPSHOT"

Error:
  [warn]    module not found: org.apache.flink#flink-azure-fs-hadoop_2.12;1.9-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\arshad.ivy2\local\org.apache.flink\flink-azure-fs-hadoop_2.12\1.9-SNAPSHOT\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-azure-fs-hadoop_2.12/1.9-SNAPSHOT/flink-azure-fs-hadoop_2.12-1.9-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\arshad.sbt\preloaded\org.apache.flink\flink-azure-fs-hadoop_2.12\1.9-SNAPSHOT\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/arshad/.sbt/preloaded/org/apache/flink/flink-azure-fs-hadoop_2.12/1.9-SNAPSHOT/flink-azure-fs-hadoop_2.12-1.9-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Apache Development Snapshot Repository: tried
[warn]   https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/flink/flink-azure-fs-hadoop_2.12/1.9-SNAPSHOT/flink-azure-fs-hadoop_2.12-1.9-SNAPSHOT.pom

Answer (score 0):

flink-azure-fs-hadoop was added in [FLINK-12115](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-12115), which will be part of the upcoming Flink 1.9 release.

The artifacts from nightly SNAPSHOT builds are at https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/flink/ -- so look in https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/flink/flink-azure-fs-hadoop/

But keep in mind this won't be considered stable until 1.9 has been released.